# return array of json after call ajax magento 1.9.3.x

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, json

I have create a search bar for search zip code for storelocator.
So in my code, i have create a request ajax who send param of zip code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#searchzip").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var getcode = parseInt(jQuery("#postcode-search__input").val());
            var url = jQuery('#form-storelocator').attr('action');
            var form= jQuery("#form-storelocator");
              try {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: form.serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {


                        if (data['success'] === false){

                                for( var i in data) {

                                        if(jQuery.inArray(arrayzip ==data.zip)){

                                            jQuery('.storelocator-info').hide();
                                            jQuery('.storelocator-info[data-id='+data.zip+']').fadeToggle();
                                        }
                                }

                                jQuery('.storelocator-error').hide();
                           }
                            else{

                                jQuery('.storelocator-info').hide();
                                jQuery('.storelocator-error').fadeToggle();
                            }

                    }
                    });
                } 
                catch (e) {
                    console.log('error' + e);
                }

        });     

});
```

and this is my controller :

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $zipcode = (int) $params['zip']; 
    $isajax = (int) $params['isAjax']; 
    $error = false; 

        if($isajax == 1){

            $connection  = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
            $queryStore = "SELECT `store_postcode`  FROM `test_store`
                                                    WHERE  `store_postcode` LIKE :store_postcode
                                                     "; 

            $binds = array('store_postcode'=> $zipcode.'%');  
            $result = $connection->query($queryStore, $binds);

            $data = $result->fetchAll();

            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

                    if(!empty($value)){
                        $error  = true; 
                    }   

                    if ($error === false){
                        $response   =   array();
                    }

                    if ($error  === true)
                    {

                        $response['success']    =   false;
                        $response['zip'] = $value['store_postcode'];
                    }
                    else{
                        $response['success']    =   true;
                    }

            }


            // var_dump( $data);

             $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
             $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));

        }   
}
```

my response return only one result when i debug ajax with console.log(data), in my loop in javascript, i have the same result for one. Or my data in php return an array of two zipcode look that : 
[image]
in yellow this my console.log in my loop in javascript, you can see i have just one result but normally i have two result.

I don't understand where is my bug ? can you help me or explain where is my mistache ?

Thank you all for help

Answer (score 2):

These lines always reset the `$response` variable

```
if ($error === false){
    $response   =   array();
}
```

and this line `$response['zip'] = $value['store_postcode'];` always overrides any previous value you set for `$response['zip']`.
Not sure about what you are trying to achieve but maybe you want to replace

```
$response['zip'] = $value['store_postcode']
```

with

```
$response['zip'][] = $value['store_postcode']
```